# Highcharts Double Click To Select

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm currently using Highcharts v8.1.0 and I'm implementing a column chart with drill down functionality.

I'd like to implement the following:

- When a user double-clicks a column in the chart, the column is selected. Once the user has finished selecting one or more columns I'd like to use the column data to apply some filtering in another part of my application so wondering if there's a way to get all the selected items and their associated data?
- When a user just single-clicks a column, the default drill down behavior happens (this currently works)

I'm using the highcharts-custom-events plugin and can capture double-click events, but can't figure out how to set the column that was clicked as selected.

Here's my plotOptions configuration:

```
plotOptions: {
        column: {
          events: {
            dblclick: function(e){
              self.dblClickDetected = true;
              this.selected = true;
              console.log('DOUBLE CLICK', self.chart.getSelectedSeries())
            }
          }
        }
```

Here's the configuration for the drilldown event:

```
drilldown: (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            setTimeout(() => {
              if(!this.dblClickDetected){
                ...do something here...
              }
            }, 500);
            this.dblClickDetected = false;
          }
```

The behavior for single-click and double-click can be reversed if it makes it easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I prepared a demo which should help you to achieve a wanted effect.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7aubt81y/

```
 plotOptions: {
    column: {
      point: {
        events: {
          dblclick: function(e) {
            if (this.state !== 'select') {
              this.update({
                selected: true
              })
            } else {
              this.update({
                selected: false
              })
            }

          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.selected

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

EDIT

---

After digging more into this requirement I think that the best solution for this case will be creating a custom drilldown event. Below is a basic demo which should be a good start to implement it.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/21utpsoy/

The reason is that drilldown module with the `dbclick` functionality throws some errors, see: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/copL4h36/.

API to used features:

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#button
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thanks for your response. This solution doesn't work for my situation as I need to be able to support both drill down and selection. With your solution, it doesn't allow for selecting columns where drill down is also available.  Ideally, a user should be able to double-click a column to select it or single-click to perform drill down.